# poping icons over an image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, web

I am looking to have an image load first then the location icons pop over with good animations like the bounce or pop up effect. I currently have static image but want to make it more interesting.[i have attached the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaIt9.jpg)

Comment: provide your code please

Comment: use a canvas. post your code.

Comment: Something like this? - http://waynegm.github.io/imgNotes/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide all location images
    $("img.locations").toggle();

    $("img.backround-image").on("load", function() {
        $("img.locations").fadeIn();
        //Show all location images with a fade in
        //- or any other animation for all location images
    });
});
```